# Forcing expiration of API session using JWT token issued by OWIN

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt

I have a SPA type application with an ASP.NET Web Api v2 REST based API. The API session is handled by the OWIN classes making use of a JWT token.

I would like to force the API session to end if the user logs into another computer with the same ID. How can I go about forcing the expiration of the API session? Do I alter the payload of the JWT token directly? Is this even possible since the OWIN classes are handling the issuing of the JWT token?